# logging for statistics purposes in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging

I want to do some logging of actions happening on my codeigniter based server for statistics and raw material for metrics.

I wanted to use built-in logging, however:
Error - it is not an error
Debug - will give me tons of codeigniter irrelevant inforamtion
Info - is below Debug (?!?)

Any ideas?

(open a file and maintain it by myself? really?)

Comment: May be you install the laster version of php . some of php function may be deprecated

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to say